# Programatically setting an object array's object

Tags: vb.net

I have

```
Public stack() As CTest
```

I want

```
Public stack() As Object
```

The latter is giving the error "Unable to cast object of type 'Object' to 'CTest'." when used:

```
Dim thestack As CTest() = testdatabase.getStack
```

Where `testdatabase.getStack` simply returns stack();

```
Public Function getStack() As Object()
    Return stack
End Function
```

This fixes it, but it's not ideal (for me personally):

```
Dim thestack As Object() = testdatabase.getStack
```

So if I could keep the variable as-is (`Public stack() As Object`) and then do something along the lines of `class.stack() = CTest` I should be able to do `Dim thestack As CTest() = testdatabase.getStack` because the object array will programmatically have changed from `Object` to `CTest`.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: You can not programmaticly change the type of a variable.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want `Public stack() As Object`". Why do you want this?

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this would be to write a conversion function that accepts `Object` and returns `CTest`. The function itself would cast Object to the boxed datatype, assign the value of each property on the object to the new CTest object and then return it. Something like this:

```
Function ConvertToCTest(o as Object) as CTest
  dim unboxed as ObjectsDataType
  unbox = directCast(o ObjectsDataType)
  Dim result as CTest
  result.Prop1 = unboxed.Prop1
  result.Prop2 = unboxed.Prop2

  Return result
End Function
```